# Disable real-time on CloudBoost

Tags: real-time, cloudboost

I've seen that my cloudboost app is constantly doing this call:

https://realtime.cloudboost.io/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1455824292764-0

And this error is returned:

[Error] Failed to load resource: A server with the specified hostname could not be found. (socket.io, line 0)

How can I disable realtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable realtime when you init your CloudApp.

`CB.CloudApp.init('https://api.cloudboost.io', 'Your AppID', 'YourAppKey',{disableRealtime : true});`

Comment: As I think, you have solved the error 400, but, is it possible to disable this realtime calls. By the moment, I don't need real-time implementation and it would be nice deactivate it. Is it possible? Does it cause some memory loss?

Comment: It continues giving me an error when calling periodically to https://realtime.cloudboost.io/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1456383371245-16&sid=mSXOH9EuGgYr1bVzAAGn. The error given is: **{"code":1,"message":"Session ID unknown"}**

Comment: We're on this. Please expect 5 day turn around on this issue.

Comment: Any news about this!

Comment: We're working on this. Should be done in couple of days. I promise.